# What does continue do inside a nested for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
for (var i in players) {
    for (var x in players[i].bullets) {
        for (var y in xpBoosts) {
            if (something === true) {
                // do something
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What will the continue statement do? Will it cycle the innermost for loop or the outermost?

Is there any way I can get the continue statement to cycle through to the next bullet?

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log` to figure it out?

Comment: I'll try that, thanks for the tip

Comment: maybe a [dupe](/questions/11728757/why-are-continue-statements-bad-in-javascript)?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`continue` terminates the current iteration of the loop it's in. To terminate the iteration of another loop, use it with labels:

```
for (var i in players) {
    bullets: for (var x in players[i].bullets) {
        for (var y in xpBoosts) {
            if (something === true) {
                // do something
                continue bullets;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have somehow never seen this before. Ya learn something new every day. Awesome!

Comment: Good answer, I was going to update mine with the `labeled continue` but I see you've already covered it!

Answer (score 1):

In your particular code `continue` doesn't do anything.

`continue` is a keyword that will quit the current iteration of the loop and carry on with the next.

as an example:

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  if (i == 5) continue;
  console.log(i);
}
```

You'll notice that `5` is not printed to the console. When the conditional check is proven true, it continues onto the next iteration without performing the rest of the code in the block.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `continue` and `break` apply to the innermost loop. In your particular code, it will continue this loop:

```
for (var y in xpBoosts) {
```

However, this behavior can be customized through labels. For example:

```
outerLoop:
for (var i = 0; i < someVal; i++){
  middleLoop:
  for (var j = 0; j < someOtherVal; j++){
    innerLoop:
    for (var k = 0; k < yetAThirdVal; k++){
      continue;//skip to next iteration of innerLoop
      continue innerLoop;//skip to next iteration of innerLoop
      continue middleLoop;//skip to next iteration of middleLoop
      continue outerLoop;//skip to next iteration of outerLoop
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I'll leave my answer here, but I much prefer [ohlec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180279/2026606).

---

`continue` only moves on to the next iteration of the innermost `for` loop.

You could have a variable that is initialized as `false` for each bullet. You can then mark this to `true` if you continue the inside loop.

```
for (var x in players[i].bullets) {
  var skipThisBullet = false;

  for (var y in xpBoosts) {
    if (something === true) {
      // do something
      skipThisBullet = true;
      continue;
    }
  }

  if (skipThisBullet) continue;

}
```